Can't paginate using Http Client snap Post method in Snaplogic
Please help!!
I am extracting data using POST HTTP Client snap with a body filtering the data by the datetime.  I am having an issue with pagination... I do not get the next url, I just get the next increment value.  e.g. with limit of 10 starting with 0 the next increment will be after 10  then next will be after 20 etc... How do I use that to paginate. How do I configure the HTTP client snap to loop through the data and re-execute the url to retrieve the next group of records?
I have tried this pipeline where the execute pipeline snap calls a pipeline that just has the httpclient snap and ingests the after value with the next incremented value.
the first row processes 0-100;  2nd row 100-200;  and 3rd row 200-300
How can I make this loop to process all 400,000 records?


I was able to accomplish what I wanted by changing the pipeline.
I essentially used a solution provided here https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/3097822264/Pagination with a few tweaks.  I modified the HTTP Client as follows: Removed pagination configurations and the parameters configurations for both http snaps and added to the body of the 2nd HTTP snap   "after" : $splitValue, "limit" : 100    Then I was getting subsequent data.   But the data was duplicating.  So I modified the mapper for pagination as follows:
sl.range(1, parseInt($entity.total), 100)
I also changed the 1st http snap to just give me 1 record just and I used the results to get the total and I process from page 1 to the end in the rest of the pipeline so I don't do a union.
And it worked!   I am now getting subsequent data and it the records are not duplicating.
Note:  there is a HubSpot 'search' endpoint limitation that it can only return up to 10000 records so anything more than that cannot be retrieved using this method.
